# How to scan into nested structs with sqlx?

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

Let's assume that I have two models,

```golang
    type Customer struct {
       Id      int     `json:"id" db:"id"`
       Name    string  `json:"name" db:"name"`
       Address Address `json:"adress"`
    }
    
    type Address struct {
       Street string `json:"street" db:"street"`
       City   string `json:"city" db:"city"`
    }

    // ...

    customer := models.Customer{}
    err := db.Get(&customer , `select * from users where id=$1 and name=$2`, id, name)
```

But this scan throws an error as: `missing destination name street in *models.Customer`

Am I doing something wrong? As you can see I already updated the db corresponding of the value. I doubled check so case sensitivity shouldn't be a problem.
Or is it not possible using https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx?

I can see it in the documentation but still couldn't figure out how to solve it.
http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#advancedScanning

The `users` table is declared as:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
      `id` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `street` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `city` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [very link you posted](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#advancedScanning) gives you an hint about how to do this:

> StructScan is deceptively sophisticated. It supports **embedded structs**, and assigns to fields using the same precedence rules that Go uses for embedded attribute and method access

So given your DB schema, you can simply embed `Address` into `Customer`:

```
type Customer struct {
   Id     int    `json:"id" db:"id"`
   Name   string `json:"name" db:"name"`
   Address
}
```

In your original code, `Address` was a field <strike>with its own `db` tag. This is not correct, and by the way your schema has no `address` column at all.</strike> (it appears you edited it out of your code snippet)

By embedding the struct into `Customer` instead, `Address` fields including tags are promoted into `Customer` and `sqlx` will be able to populate them from your query result.

Warning: embedding the field will also flatten the output of any JSON marshalling. It will become:

```js
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "street": "bar",
    "city": "baz"
}
```

If you want to place `street` and `city` into a JSON `address` object as based on your original struct tags, the easiest way is probably to remap the DB struct to your original type.

You could also scan the query result into a `map[string]interface{}` but then you have to be careful about [how Postgres data types are represented in Go](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Data_Types).

Answer (score 2):

Using [Carta](https://github.com/jackskj/carta) a lightweight library can help:

Sample Schema:

```
type Blog struct {
        Id     int    `db:"blog_id"`
        Title  string `db:"blog_title"`
        Posts  []Post
        Author Author
}
type Post struct {
        Id   int    `db:"posts_id"`
        Name string `db:"posts_name"`
}
type Author struct {
        Id       int    `db:"author_id"`
        Username string `db:"author_username"`
}
```

Query:

```
select
       id          as  blog_id,
       title       as  blog_title,
       P.id        as  posts_id,         
       P.name      as  posts_name,
       A.id        as  author_id,      
       A.username  as  author_username
from blog
       left outer join author A    on  blog.author_id = A.id
       left outer join post P      on  blog.id = P.blog_id
```

Using it:

```
// 1) Run your query
if rows, err = sqlDB.Query(blogQuery); err != nil {
    // error
}

// 2) Instantiate a slice(or struct) which you want to populate, Dummy example.
blogs := []Blog{}

// 3) Map the SQL rows to your slice
carta.Map(rows, &blogs)
```

Carta will map the SQL rows while keeping track of those relationships.

SQL Results:

```
rows:
blog_id | blog_title | posts_id | posts_name | author_id | author_username
1       | Foo        | 1        | Bar        | 1         | John
1       | Foo        | 2        | Baz        | 1         | John
2       | Egg        | 3        | Beacon     | 2         | Ed
```

Final Result:

```
blogs:
[{
    "blog_id": 1,
    "blog_title": "Foo",
    "author": {
        "author_id": 1,
        "author_username": "John"
    },
    "posts": [{
            "post_id": 1,
            "posts_name": "Bar"
        }, {
            "post_id": 2,
            "posts_name": "Baz"
        }]
}, {
    "blog_id": 2,
    "blog_title": "Egg",
    "author": {
        "author_id": 2,
        "author_username": "Ed"
    },
    "posts": [{
            "post_id": 3,
            "posts_name": "Beacon"
        }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and came up with a slightly more elegant solution than @blackgreen's.

He's right, the easiest way is to embed the objects, but I do it in a temporary object instead of making the original messier.

You then add a function to convert your temp (flat) object into your real (nested) one.

```
    type Customer struct {
       Id      int     `json:"id" db:"id"`
       Name    string  `json:"name" db:"name"`
       Address Address `json:"adress"`
    }
    
    type Address struct {
       Street string `json:"street" db:"street"`
       City   string `json:"city" db:"city"`
    }
    
    type tempCustomer struct {
          Customer
          Address
    }

    func (c *tempCustomer) ToCustomer() Customer {
        customer := c.Customer
        customer.Address = c.Address
        return customer
    }
```

Now you can scan into tempCustomer and simply call tempCustomer.ToCustomer before you return. This keeps your JSON clean and doesn't require a custom scan function.

Comment: This is not very elegant. My observation is that each every library is not 100% good. They all have something missing, and it's things like this that make be not like go library developers