# Scan a Sql Query sqlx.Rows into a Nested Structure in golang

Tags: postgresql, go, nested, sqlx

I have three following tables:

```
create table A (
  a_id     varchar(256) not null unique,
  a_name   varchar(256)
);

create table B (
  b_id     varchar(256) not null,
  b_a_id   varchar(256) not null,
  b_name   varchar(256),
  FOREIGN KEY (b_a_id) REFERENCES a (a_id)
);

create table C (
  c_id     varchar(256) not null,
  c_a_id   varchar(256) not null,
  c_name   varchar(256),
  FOREIGN KEY (c_a_id) REFERENCES a (a_id)
);

insert into A(a_id, a_name) values('1234', 'a_name_1');

insert into B(b_id, b_a_id, b_name) values('B1','1234', 'b_name_1');
insert into B(b_id, b_a_id, b_name) values('B2','1234', 'b_name_2');

insert into C(c_id, c_a_id, c_name) values('C1','1234', 'c_name_1');
insert into C(c_id, c_a_id, c_name) values('C2','1234', 'c_name_2');
insert into C(c_id, c_a_id, c_name) values('C3','1234', 'c_name_3');
```

I have the following Structs in golang:

```
type A struct {
     a_id   string    `db:"a_id"`
     a_name string    `db:"a_name"`
     b      *B        `db:"b"`
     c      *C        `db:"c"`
}

type B struct {
    b_id    string     `db:"b_id"`
    b_name  string     `db:"b_name"`
    b_a_id  string     `db:"b_a_id"`
}

type C struct {
    c_id    string     `db:"c_id"`
    c_name  string     `db:"c_name"`
    c_a_id  string     `db:"c_a_id"`
}
```

I want to scan the rows I get from executing the join query:
`SELECT * from A INNER JOIN B ON a_id=b_a_id inner join C on c_a_id=a_id;`

Into Struct A using rows.StructScan() in Golang but I am not able to do that. How Do I scan
a join query result into a nested struct and I don't want to individually scan each column as there are a lot of columns as a result of the join query going forward.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I came up with a solution that should work also for you. First, let me present the working code, and then I'll explain the relevant parts:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type A struct {
    Id   string `db:"a_id"`
    Name string `db:"a_name"`
    B
    C
}

type B struct {
    Id   string `db:"b_id"`
    AId  string `db:"b_a_id"`
    Name string `db:"b_name"`
}

type C struct {
    Id   string `db:"c_id"`
    AId  string `db:"c_a_id"`
    Name string `db:"c_name"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := sqlx.Open("postgres", "host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    a := []A{}
    rows, err := db.Queryx("SELECT * from A INNER JOIN B ON a_id=b_a_id inner join C on c_a_id=a_id;")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var record A
        if err := rows.StructScan(&record); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        a = append(a, record)
    }

    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, v := range a {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

##### Structs definition

Here, I fixed the structs' definition by embedding `B` and `C` into the `A` struct. Furthermore, I also fixed the name as long as they didn't collide with the others (e.g. it's completely safe to have the `Id` field in all of the three structs).

##### Fetching data

The other relevant part is fetching the data from Postgres. Here you've to use the `Queryx` method and provide to it the SQL query you've correctly written.
However, you should use the methods provided by the `database/sql` package when dealing with multiple rows (as in our case). `Next` and `Err` are self-explanatory so I won't spend any time over them.
`StructScan` is the method that does the trick. It puts the current query into a loop-scoped variable called `record` of type `A` (which is our parent struct).

If you give a try to this code it should work also for you, if not let me know!

Comment: Hi @Abinaya Hariharan, did you manage it?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this answer [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76063415/12193818)

Using a light weight library [Carta](https://github.com/jackskj/carta) can map SQL results to nested structs.